# Clion Header Search Paths ignoring folders

Tags: cmake, path, header, clion, include-path

I have a CLion project, where i need to include a file from /usr/include. I can see all the folders in Header Search Paths but the one i need. [Header Search Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH2Rf.png). 
I edited the CMakeLists.txt with `include_directories(/usr/include/mysql`). The folder is there, i can see it, but it keeps saying `mysql.h: no such file or directory`. Whats the problem?

Comment: Please, add to the question post your **code** and **exact error message** (which should include information about which file is compiled). Otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: Why not use the same include as regular folks (`#include <mysql/mysql.h>`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code and the error message:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9vPY.png)

Comment: please for posting additional details like code snippet or description, edit the question itself